# Can Zoom Video SDK do Compositions like Twilio?

Tags: twilio, zoom-sdk, twilio-video

So Twilio just announced EOL for Programmable Video:

https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/programmable-video-eol-notice

We rely heavily on Twilio Programmable Video for the following reasons:

1. Split audio streams for participants
2. Millisecond-level accuracy of timings and syncing across participants
3. Composition service to create custom video outputs post-flight

They advocate Zoom Video SDK which does not appear to have (1) or (3) despite the claim of "complete feature parity".

Can Zoom Video SDK do compositions and split audio, or, can you suggest another platform which is actually on par with Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom Video SDK Developer Advocate here, happy to answer this question or allow you to share more on our [devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/c/video-sdk/twilio-migration/82).

1. To split audio tracks, you can use our [muteUserAudioLocally](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/custom/web/modules/Stream.html#muteUserAudioLocally) feature, which allows you to control which user's audio is played to which user/s. You can also [control volume](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/custom/web/modules/Stream.html#adjustUserAudioVolumeLocally) in the same manner, or use our [Subsession feature](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/subsessions/) which allows you to build breakout rooms within the Video SDK.
2. User timing and syncing is built in to the Video SDK, but we also offer a [command channel feature](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/command-channel/) if you want to send and receive data between connected users.
3. [Cloud Recording](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/recording/) in the Video SDK by default handles the composition for you, however, you do have access to certain [output configurations](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/recording/#recording-options). We also offer the ability to [record individual user audio and video streams (see `cloud_recording_option`)](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/auth/#payload) so you can create your own custom outputs.